# Bootstrap height and width attribute does not work properly

Tags: html, css

I designed three bootstrap cards which includes an image and a description below it. As I want to show them similar in size I added img width and height attribute the image. But due to a bug this height and width properties do not work properly. Three images are shown in three different sizes. I have produced the code below.

Can anybody figerout what is the bug here?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">

    <!--Card-->
    <div class="card">

      <!--Card image-->
      <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
        <img src="img/sigiriya.jpg" class="img-fluid" height="500px" width="500px" alt="">
        <a>
          <div class="mask"></div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <!--Card content-->
      <div class="card-block">
        <!--Title-->
        <h4 class="card-title">Card with waves effect</h4>
        <!--Text-->
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#!" class="btn btn-indigo">Button</a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--/.Card-->

  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">

    <!--Card-->
    <div class="card">

      <!--Card image-->
      <!--Card image-->
      <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/nuwara_eliya.jpg" alt="Card image cap" height="500px" width="500px">
        <a>
          <div class="mask"></div>
        </a>
      </div>


      <!--Card content-->
      <div class="card-block">
        <!--Title-->
        <h4 class="card-title">Classic card</h4>
        <!--Text-->
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--/.Card-->

  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">

    <!--Card-->
    <div class="card">

      <!--Card image-->
      <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
        <img src="img/ella.jpg" class="img-fluid" height="500px" width="500px" alt="">
        <a>
          <div class="mask"></div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <!--Card content-->
      <div class="card-block">
        <!--Title-->
        <h4 class="card-title">Card with waves effect</h4>
        <!--Text-->
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#!" class="btn btn-pink">Button</a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--/.Card-->

  </div>
```

Comment: If you add a fixed width you need to remove img-fluid class, you can read more about responsive images at https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/images/#responsive-images

Comment: @Troyer I have already add img-fluid class but three imags are in 3 different sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code. it's working fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">

    <!--Card-->
    <div class="card">

      <!--Card image-->
      <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
        <img src="b.png" height="500" width="500" alt="">
        <a>
          <div class="mask"></div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <!--Card content-->
      <div class="card-block">
        <!--Title-->
        <h4 class="card-title">Card with waves effect</h4>
        <!--Text-->
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#!" class="btn btn-indigo">Button</a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--/.Card-->

  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">

    <!--Card-->
    <div class="card">

      <!--Card image-->
      <!--Card image-->
      <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
        <img src="profile.jpg" alt="Card image cap" height="500" width="500">
        <a>
          <div class="mask"></div>
        </a>
      </div>


      <!--Card content-->
      <div class="card-block">
        <!--Title-->
        <h4 class="card-title">Classic card</h4>
        <!--Text-->
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--/.Card-->

  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">

    <!--Card-->
    <div class="card">

      <!--Card image-->
      <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
        <img src="profile.jpg" height="500" width="500" alt="">
        <a>
          <div class="mask"></div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <!--Card content-->
      <div class="card-block">
        <!--Title-->
        <h4 class="card-title">Card with waves effect</h4>
        <!--Text-->
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#!" class="btn btn-pink">Button</a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--/.Card-->

  </div>
```

Comment: You can point out the editing which you have done for a better view.

Answer (score 0):

By removing class="img-fluid" property we can adjust images according our preferrences

Answer (score 0):

- img-fluid class it is available for bootstrap v4, but you include CDN v3
- img-fluid just apply max-with: 100%; height: auto; so it is not conflict with width and height of html attribute. Maybe other style apply to them and you can user browser debug to find what style that apply to your images.
- You should use width and height of css to be sure it has no other style to override it.